# how to add line break in HTML using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

By "line break" I do not mean the `<br />` tag. Rather what I mean is the actual line break itself in the HTML like below:

```
<html>
    <body> <--This is on a new line
```

I have a set of div's that are `display:inline-block` and depending on whether or not the following `<div>` is on a new line or the same line it displays slightly differently. Generating these div's in PHP requires that these are on new lines. The catch is that I need to generate these same div's in jQuery by using a `$(this).clone().appendTo(element)` and I don't know how to add the line break using jQuery.

So is there some kind of trick that will append these div's on new lines or some kind of css property that would display it the same either way?

This is what my html looks like using PHP:

```
<div>
    <label>Input label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Input label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

This is what it's like using jQuery:

```
<div>
    <label>Input label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div><div>
    <label>Input label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly try setting the raw HTML, and in the string, include '\n'.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher I've added my HTML. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Can you do that w/ jQuery? I don't know how I would do that.

Comment: I'd go with Dan's guess. In the PHP source code you may have things on different lines. But you're not outputting a newline character to the browser.

Comment: But why does it matter? What effect does it have?

Comment: All whitespace in HTML is consumed equally by the browsers' HTML parser, so space(s), tab(s) or newline(s) all will result in the same layout in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the string you are using for your html, use a `\n`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. I used $(element).append('\n') before my cloning action.

Comment: Very nice!  Escapes can be a real time-saver in both PHP and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP probably looks like this...
( Only relevant section shown )

```
echo '</div>';
echo '<div>';
```

Add in an echo...

```
echo '</div>';
echo "\n";
echo '<div>';
```

Comment: His PHP output is fine, it's his jQuery/JavaScript that's causing the problem.